# Unable to upload 1.5 GB file on google drive in perl

Tags: perl

I have tried to upload zip file on Google drive in perl. I have used Net::Google::Drive::Simple module. I have used $gd->file_upload( $file, $dir_id ) function of this module.Its working file for file size less than 1 GB. **but when I have tried to upload file more than 1 GB, It throws error "Out of Memory!".**

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the 
[`Net::Google::Drive::Simple`](http://metacpan.org/module/Net::Google::Drive::Simple) module
reads the file to be uploaded by using
`slurp` from
[`Sysadm::Install`](http://metacpan.org/module/Sysadm::Install), so the 1.5GB is enough to break Perl's memory limit. And it's made worse by *copying* the data into the `HTTP::Message::Request` structure. There doesn't appear to be another module on CPAN that will do this for you

I'm considering writing a subclass that does an incremental read, but I can't offer another solution at present

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are hitting the 15Gb free storage limit (shared across Drive, Gmail, and Google+ Photos)?